# Force zoom-in on mobile devices

Tags: android, apache, mobile, themes, viewport

I am currently using Apaxy (an Apache directory browser). The theme looks beautiful on PC, but on mobile, it's a little too zoomed out. Is there any way I could force-zoom in if a mobile device is detected?

For a little more detail, this is what I mean:

- What actually happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRKqs.jpg
- What I would like to happen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/unJyZ.jpg

I can't seem to figure out a way to do this using viewport, but maybe I'm just not thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the viewport meta tag to set an initial-scale: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

However, setting an initial scale will load the page "off-center" since it'll start off zoomed into the top left corner. I think what you really want is to set width=device-width in the viewport meta so that the page lays out into a size appropriate for the screen size.

e.g. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

Comment: This is already on the site. As I said, though it may not have been clear, I have tried using the viewport meta tag but I cannot seem to accomplish what I need using it.

Comment: Ah, in that case the viewport meta cannot help you since your content is sized too small and there's no way to position the viewport with the meta tag (so that it's centred). The correct way to do this would be to make the page and its content responsive based on the size of the screen.